# XSLT surround with element

Tags: xml, xslt

Ok, I feel like this is a really stupid question, but I've been trying for some time to get it so my XSLT file will spit out the output encapsulated in some arbitrary element, let's call it "root".  How would I achieve this?

Here is my current XSLT if that helps at all:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="DCField">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@FieldValueType='None'">
            <xsl:element name="{Name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="{@FieldValueType}">
                <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I want it so my output looks like:

```
<root>
    <element1>
    <element2>
    ...
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the contents of your root-matching template in a `<root>` tag.

http://www.xmlplayground.com/RYv2XW (see output source)

Comment: Thanks, but that results in every element being wrapped in a <root> tag, which is not what I'm going for

Comment: Aha!  That worked like a charm.  I knew it had to be something simple that I was just unable to come up with.  Thanks a bunch

Comment: that link has been taken over by a meaningless cyber-squatting site that prevents you from leaving with popups